# In r, is there a way of separating this column into latitude and longitude columns?

Tags: r

[image]

I am trying to separate a column into two, latitude and longitude. The column has the format of PRINT(-71.461299 42.756061)

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for

```
strsplit("-71.461299 42.756061", " ")
```

?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear to me whether PRINT is part of your data. If its not, then your best bet is the tidyverse `separate` function:

```
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)
data.frame(x = "-71.461299 42.756061") %>% separate(x, c("lat", "lng"), sep=" ")
```

If PRINT and the parentheses are part of your data, then you want something like this:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
data.frame(x = "PRINT(-71.461299 42.756061)") %>% 
     mutate(
          lat = str_match(x, "([0-9\\.]+)\\s[0-9\\.]+")[,2], 
          lng = str_match(x, "[0-9\\.]+\\s([0-9\\.]+)")[,2]
     ) %>% select(-x) %>% mutate_if(is.character, as.numeric)
```

Learning this package set (dplyr, stringr, tidyr) will benefit your R work greatly over time.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have data such as :

```
df <- data.frame(Location = c("POINT(-71.461299 42.756061)", 
                "POINT(-71.4619 42.7560)"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

You can use `tidyr::extract` as :

```
tidyr::extract(df, Location, c('lat', 'long'), '\\((.*)\\s(.*)\\)')

#         lat      long
#1 -71.461299 42.756061
#2   -71.4619   42.7560
```

This extracts everything between parenthesis (`()`) into two columns separated by space.